# SVM Loss Function

Tags: python, svm, loss

```
def svm_loss_naive(W, X, y):
"""
SVM loss function, naive implementation calculating loss for each sample
using loops.    

Inputs:
- X: A numpy array of shape (n, m) containing data(samples).
- y: A numpy array of shape (m, ) containing labels
- W: A numpy array of shape (p, n) containing weights.  
   
"""
# Compute the loss
num_classes = W.shape[0] # classes weights are in row wise fashion
num_samples = X.shape[1] # samples of unknown images are in column-wise fashion
loss = 0.0
delta = 1 # SVM parameter
for i in range(num_samples):
    scores = np.dot(W, X[:,i])
    correct_class_score = scores[y[i]] 
    for j in range(num_classes):       
        if j == y[i]:
            continue
        margin = max(0, scores[j] - correct_class_score + delta )
        loss = loss + margin

# Average loss
loss = loss / num_samples

return loss
```

according to my understanding of the python code

1. we are first calculating the score for the 1st category by multiplying the weight of the 1st row with the 1st sample column
2. then we are fetching the correct_class_score of the ith sample that we have stored in array y
3. then we are iterating over the number of classes(let it be 3) the thing I didn't understand is
   what j == y[i] is doing?
   I mean to say when j will be equal to y[i] as j ranges from 0 to 2 and y[i] is just the index of the correct_class_score for the ith sample

the rest of the code I understood thnx in advance

Answer (score -1):

This is the SVM loss (data loss) function definition:

[image: SVM data loss function]

In the internal summation the j index equal to y[i] is explicitly escluded